# Numbers/Text/Picture recognition in an Image using Java

Tags: java, image-processing, image-recognition

I'm working on a university project, I have to find an existing Java code that allows number recognition on a picture of a soccer t-shirt.

The title is more general because the problem can be seen as number recognition, text recognition, or finding a picture in a picture. I need a program that gives an input image square number in a minimum inclusion square (like OpenCV allows doing with faces) and (if possible) tells the user if the number was found or not.

I tried using tesseract, aspose, and many codes posted on this site, sourceforge and similar but none weres useful. I think the easiest way is using OpenCV, maybe using a classifier or a neural network but I'm really new to this. Can someone help me linking me an implementation of my problem or in some other way? Thank you and sorry for my terrible English :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Leadtools Recognition SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/engine/recognition) in your application.

You can leverage the OcrEngine class, which will allow you to recognize text, whether letters or numbers, from a loaded image.

**DISCLOSURE: I am an employee of the company offering this toolkit.**

Here is some sample code:

```
String tifFileName = "C:\\LEADTOOLS21\\Resources\\Images\\ocr1.tif"; 

RasterCodecs codecs = new RasterCodecs(); 
RasterImage image = codecs.load(tifFileName);

OcrEngine ocrEngine = OcrEngineManager.createEngine(OcrEngineType.LEAD); 
ocrEngine.startup(new RasterCodecs(), new DocumentWriter(), null, null); 
         
OcrDocument ocrDocument = ocrEngine.getDocumentManager().createDocument(); 
OcrPage ocrPage = ocrDocument.getPages().addPage(image, null);

ocrPage.recognize(null); 

// Show the results 
String text = ocrPage.getText(0); 
System.out.println(text);
```